# $C(n)+P(n)+S(n)$ always composites?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $C(n)$ be the concatenation of first $n$ primes, let $P(n)$ be the product of first $n$ primes, and let $S(n)$ be the sum of the first $n$ primes. It is not surprising that $C(n) - P(n) - S(n)$ is always composite.

Is $C(n) +P(n) + S(n)$ always composite? If $n$ is even then $C(n) + P(n) + S(n)$ is also even, for odd $n$ , $C(n) +P(n) + S(n)$ is often divisible by $5$ and small odd primes.

I have checked $n$ up to 1000. Is there  prime number of the form $C(n) + P(n) +S(n)$ ?

Comment: It seems like $C(411)+P(411)+S(411)$ is prime - verification required, found with Wolfram Mathematica 10.0

Comment: O okay, It's like an answer to me. Would you give me one more prime of such form : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=411$ we find a prime number, $C(411)+P(411)+S(411)$. Found and verified with Wolfram Mathematica 10.0. It is also the only solution for $n<3000$.